# vuetify update v-combobox list

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

what i'm doing wrong. 
i wand to update dropdown list from v-combobox.
I tried updating items object, but nothing happens, the combobox will unupdate

```
"vue": "^2.5.22",
"vuetify": "^1.4.3",
```

please show hier https://codepen.io/vincent4/pen/KJpYMz?editors=1010

any idea?

thank you

Comment: hier ist the solution https://codepen.io/vincent4/pen/yZYyBe

Comment: Please add some relevant code directly in your question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `$set` helper from vue in order to trigger the update correctly. See [Reactivity in depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#ad):

```
change(){
  this.$set(this.items, 0, { id: 1, value: Math.random().toString(36).replace('.','')})
  console.log(this.items[0])
  this.newValue = this.items[0]
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YBywRb?editors=1010